# Changing Django template editor in Aptana

Tags: django, templates, aptana, syntax-highlighting

Currently, when I have code like this:

```
series: {{ traffic_json|safe }},
```

Aptana flags the second of the double brackets as "Syntax error: unexpected token '{'" and "Syntax error: unexpected token '}'"  AFAIK, that's valid syntax for printing a variable's value in Django's templating language, is there any way to get Aptana to recognize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the Package Explorer on the file you wish to open with different editor  --> Open with --> Choose any editor you wish,  I have around 10 different editors to choose from.

Comment: I've tried changing the editors, they all misrecognize this as an error.